# Filtering and displaying a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am currently retrieving a CSV file with PHP and displaying it in a table format via the following method:

```
    <?php
        if (($file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== false) {
            $str = '';
            $str .= '<table>';
            while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
                $str .= '<tr>';
                foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
                    $str .= "<td valign='top'>$value</td>";
                }
                $str .= '</tr>';
                $str .= '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';
            }
            fclose($file_handle);
            $str .= '</table>';
            echo $str;
        }
    ?>
```

This works fine and is nice and straight forward. However, I would like to only display rows from the CSV file when that row contains a specific value. I've been trying to get my head around how I can do this, but I'm not familiar enough with CSV manipulation to get anything working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

As an example, say my CSV file is structured like this

```
Timestamp, F, staff, kitchen, 34
Timestamp, P, staff, floor, 32
Timestamp, F, staff, floor, 33
Timestamp, F, contractor, kitchen, 65
Timestamp, P, staff, kitchen, 34
```

If I only want to output rows where the final value is, for example, 34, how would I do this?

Comment: since you're using a database, load the file then use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It's not about csv manipulation just check if the array value you are interested in matches the value you are looking for before you echo out that row of data. As you have done fgetcsv, $data is just an array

Comment: @Fred-ii- Where does the OP say they are using a database?

Comment: @Anigel Ummm... look at the tag perhaps? ;-) being [database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database)

Comment: .............. there you go. You can delete your ping to me. @Anigel and I'll delete mine. They're taking up room for nothing.

Comment: Isn't WHERE limited to just SQL? I was trying to use something like if (in_array( $your_value_to_search, $line_of_text)) { but wasn't having any luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is nothing in the code to indicate a database is in use or that the OP has any ability to change the query run on the database if one even exists. The OP may even be referring to the csv file as the "database"

Comment: Sorry everyone. I added database to the tag by mistake. But this is indeed a CSV file.

Comment: @Anigel Ok.... the OP just deleted the database tag, so I have no idea why they did in the first place. Why don't you ask them instead? My comments were relevant from [the get go](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40285479/1).

Comment: @user5838014 Given you added the database tag by mistake, "why" don't you use one? It will make things a lot simpler, really. Rather than text files which are a lot of work.

Comment: *"Isn't WHERE limited to just SQL?"* - Yes it is and that's why you should be using a database for all this. It will make your life a LOT easier. @user5838014 *Believe me*.

Comment: I would, and that's what I'm familiar with. However, I'm reading live data from a Google Spreadsheet, and the easiest way to get it to play nice with PHP is to output it as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip rows with simple continue statement. For example

```
<?php
    if (($file_handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== false) {
        $str = '';
        $row = 0; 
        $str .= '<table>';
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
            $row++;
            if ($data[4] != '34' && $row > 1) continue; // *** skip rows without '34' ***
            $str .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
                $str .= "<td valign='top'>$value</td>";
            }
            $str .= '</tr>';
            $str .= '<tr><td><br></td></tr>';
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        $str .= '</table>';
        echo $str;
    }
?>
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks. I should have thought of that.

Comment: Although, is there a way to not do this for the first line, so to keep the heading?

Comment: Sure, why not. I edited script to prevent filtering of header row. There is no special magic when working with CSV in php, all filtering should be done with PHP code