# CSV Filter Column & Rows and echo as XML - - I have working code to echo HTML Table

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have found many threads to echo a CSV file as XML, but cannot work out how to filter rows and columns.

The code below does exactly what I want but the output is an HTML table.

I need help to create similar code for xml output.

**Scenario**
sitemap.csv

```
1,https://example.com/page1,monthly,1
7,https://example.com/page2,monthly,0.5
14,https://example.com/page3,monthly,0.5
21,https://example.com/page4,monthly,0.5
```

This is a static website where all pages are already created but should only appear in sitemap at rate of 1 per week ie 10 days after 09 Feb 2020 $launchdate only first two rows should be visible in sitemap.

1st column should not be echoed - it is used to determine if that row should be echoed at load time.

I have looked at many scripts to convert csv to XML but all of them display all columns. I have tried for hours to come up with a solution to create results in XML format.

I know final solution will need to **include** something like:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL; 
    echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">' .PHP_EOL;
```

I know final solution will need to **exclude** the echo of date data at top - currently used for testing

I know final solution will need to replace the column descriptors

```
eg Loc will become <loc> URL </loc>  then <lastmod> <changefreq>  <priority>
```

======

```
Working code to echo HTML table
<?php
//Sources for this solution
// https://thisinterestsme.com/reading-csv-file-with-php/
// and &  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285479/filtering-and-displaying-a-csv-file-with-php 

// Final solution should be xml not HTML table

$date = date("Y-m-d");  // Todays Date
$date_number = strtotime($date); // Todays date as Integer
$launchdate_number = strtotime('2020-02-09'); //Launch Date as Integer 1581206400
$days_since_launch = ($date_number - $launchdate_number) / 86400; // Days since Launch date

// Echo data for testing, will not be in the final XML file
echo "date ";
echo $date;
echo " ";
echo "date_number ";
echo $date_number;
echo " ";
echo "launchdate ";
echo $launchdate_number;
echo " ";
echo "days_since_launch ";
echo " ";
echo $days_since_launch;
echo "<br>";
$fileHandle = fopen("sitemap.csv", "r");

//Loop through the CSV rows.
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    if ($row[0] > $days_since_launch) continue; // display only pages were value in 1st column[0]less that $days_since_launch
    //Print out my column data - exclude 1st column[0]
    echo 'Loc: ' . $row[1] . '<br>';
    echo 'Lastmod: ' . $date . '<br>';
    echo 'changefreq: ' . $row[2] . '<br>';
    echo 'priority: ' . $row[3] . '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}
       fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: Seems you are almost there. You just need to construct your XML as text, the same way you are now constructing HTML. Probably you should define or follow a given XML Schema.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have sufficient skills to get a result form your suggestion. After many hours I have solved my query and will add it below.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I managed to find a solution which reads a CSV file and echos a valid xml sitemap. Thanks to sources in comments of code.

```
<?php   
//Sources for this solution
    // https://thisinterestsme.com/reading-csv-file-with-php/
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285479/filtering-and-displaying-a-csv-file-with-php 
    // https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/make-dynamic-xml-sitemap-in-php-script.html

    header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; 

    $date = date("Y-m-d");  // Todays Date
    $date_number = strtotime($date); // Todays date as Integer
    $launchdate_number = strtotime('2020-02-09'); //Launch Date as Integer 1581206400
    $days_since_launch = ($date_number - $launchdate_number) / 86400; // Days since Launch date

    // Echo data for testing, will not be in the final XML file


    $fileHandle = fopen("sitemap.csv", "r");
    echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
    //Loop through the CSV rows.
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($row[0] > $days_since_launch) continue; // display only pages were value in 1st column[0]less that $days_since_launch
        //Print out my column data - exclude 1st column[0]
     echo '<url>' . PHP_EOL;
     echo '<loc>'. $row[1] .'</loc>' . PHP_EOL;
     echo '<lastmod>'.$date.'</lastmod>' . PHP_EOL;
     echo '<changefreq>'. $row[3] .'</changefreq>' . PHP_EOL;
     echo '<priority>'. $row[4] .'</priority>' . PHP_EOL;
     echo '</url>' . PHP_EOL;  

    }
    echo '</urlset>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Looks ok for a particular XML structure. Well done.